# How to add needed folders to the same directory as that of jar file in eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, api, jar, config, wordnet

I am trying to use Hindi wordnet java api in Eclipse IDE.

In Readme file of the api it is written that we must add two folders to the same directory where .jar file resides.

I have included .jar file to classpath of the project.
But I don't know how to add those two folders to same directory as that of the `.jar` file.

Now `.jar` file is in `myProject->src->Referenced Libraries`

Without including these folders I am getting following error

```
Error reading configuration file. Make sure its correct path is specified.
```

I checked api folder->config-> .config file where these folders are mentioned. Means .jar need those folders at runtime.

Totally confused.. how to use those folders and jar files in Eclipse IDE.

**NOTE** : Everything works perfectly when I run it from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be too late for OP, but I just thought that it would be a good idea to post it in case if someone else faces this problem. Although the answer is written for Eclipse users as per OP's request, similar steps should work in any IDE.

Here is what one needs to do in order to make Hindi WN APIs work:

1. Download APIs from [this link](http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/wordnet/webhwn/API_downloaderInfo.php).
2. Create a new empty `Java Project` in Eclipse and copy the contents of this zip under it (you don't need to copy `src` and `.class` files). Move `Examples.java` under `src/` of your project.
3. Go to `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries` and add `JHWNL.jar` (this should be already present under root of your project if you followed previous step).

After this, the code should compile and you would be able to use the APIs.

Further, if you want to run all tests inside `Examples.java`, you need to download Hindi Wordnet itself (from [this link](http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/wordnet/webhwn/downloaderInfo.php)). Extract its contents somewhere and copy extracted `database/` and `MorphHIN/` directories under the root of your Eclipse project.

**Note:** By default, Eclipse might use an encoding other than `UTF-8`. This might garble the output in the console. You may change it under `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace` by selecting appropriate `Text file encoding`.

Hope that helps!